# Remove commas from within a CSV field with only bash script

Tags: text-processing

I have a CSV file and I want to edit the ipAddress column to remove the comma. Basically `120.30.19, 119.234.76` should be changed to
`120.30.19 119.234.76`

Here is my data:

```
Name,Age,Gender,id,Phone,Address,City,State,Country,IPAddress,OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2
John,25,Male,12,123,Main St,New York,NY,USA,120.30.19, 119.234.761,Value1,Value2
```

I want it to be:

```
Name,Age,Gender,id,Phone,Address,City,State,Country,IPAddress,OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2
John,25,Male,12,123,Main St,New York,NY,USA,120.30.19 119.234.761,Value1,Value2
```

The only thing I want to change is the IPAddress. I got this command to work:
`sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{9\}[^,]*\),/\1/g'` data.csv to work but what this does is merge IPAddress and OtherColumn1 so I end up getting something like:

```
Name,Age,Gender,id,Phone,Address,City,State,Country,IPAddressOtherColumn1,OtherColumn2
John,25,Male,12,123,Main St,New York,NY,USA,120.30.19 119.234.761,Value1,Value2
```

I know this is a simple fix but any help would be appreciated, I'm honestly not sure whats wrong with the sed command and why its doing this. This is the first time I've had to do shell script or regex so definitely lot to improve on my end.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, there's a [discussion in meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7083/do-we-have-a-go-to-reference-qa-for-i-want-to-do-grep-sed-awk-on-xml-json-y) addressing cases like this. Maybe you are interested.

Comment: Why do you say essentially, 'IP adresses should be in a single field without a comma'? If you look at [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), the instructions are that _"Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and __commas__ should be enclosed in double-quotes."_

Answer (score 3):

Your "CSV" file is broken.  You should fix whatever generated it so that it double-quotes any fields that contain comma characters.  And then use perl (e.g. with [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)) or python (e.g. [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)) or [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) to work with them - sed and awk are OK-ish for simple comma-delimited files, but not for actual CSV files with quoted fields containing commas, newlines, or other problematic characters.

However, it seems that your IP addresses are separated by a comma AND a space.  If that's always the case (and no other fields begin with a space) then you can target that with your sed command - For example:

```
sed -e 's/, / /g'
```

Comment: Besides, `120.30.19` is NOT a valid IP address.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually clever of doing it! However, when I open it in an Excel file, the second ip address goes to the next column. Is there a way to fix this or is it just because of the formatting?

Comment: I don't use excel at all but i'd guess that you're telling excel to use spaces or commas as the separator when importing the file.  Make sure that the dialog is set to using only commas.  I use libreoffice calc sometimes and it has that option in the import dialog, so i'd be surprised if excel didn't have something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `1 !`  before your pattern like this

```
sed '1 ! s/\(\([^,]*,\)\{9\}[^,]*\),/\1/g'
```

this would skip the header

**Output**

```
$ sed '1 ! s/\(\([^,]*,\)\{9\}[^,]*\),/\1/g' d
Name,Age,Gender,id,Phone,Address,City,State,Country,IPAddress,OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2
John,25,Male,12,123,Main St,New York,NY,USA,120.30.19 119.234.761,Value1,Value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF>12{$10=$10 $11; $11=$12; $12=$13; sub(/,[^,]*$/,"")} 1' file
Name,Age,Gender,id,Phone,Address,City,State,Country,IPAddress,OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2
John,25,Male,12,123,Main St,New York,NY,USA,120.30.19 119.234.761,Value1,Value2
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10 (NF>12 ? $11 : ""), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
Name,Age,Gender,id,Phone,Address,City,State,Country,IPAddress,OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2
John,25,Male,12,123,Main St,New York,NY,USA,120.30.19 119.234.761,Value1,Value2
```